# Why are xforms-submit-error event properties allways empty?

Tags: error-handling, orbeon, xforms, submission

I've just started with orbeon and xforms for some project.
I have Orbeon succesfuly integrated with my test application as xforms engine (separate deployment with crosscontext).

Now, xforms basics are behind me and I needed to implement some kind of error checking after submit. So I'm trying to handle xforms-submit-error for example like this (this is modified example from w3.org):

```
<xf:submission action="/processor500" method="post" id="submission1" replace="none">
    <xf:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal">submission1 error (<output value="event('response-status-code')"/>)</xf:message>
</xf:submission>
```

/process500 is empty servlet, which just raise RuntimeException so it is returning 500 response code.
But response-status-code in event is allways empty. Any of event properties are allways empty and i just can't figure it why (google didn't help this time).

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: As avernet answered namespace is missing for the output tag. Another suggestion, you can also find the error details when you turn log4j on with debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event('response-status-code')` on `xforms-submit-error` is supported, and your example doesn't work most likely because you're missing a prefix on the `<output>` (it should be `<xf:output>`). Also see this [XForms test case](https://gist.github.com/1685838) showing the `event('response-status-code')` in action.

Comment: I feel so dumb now. What a shame. Thanks guys.